# How to set up automatic always-on SSH tunnels on Windows 10 (or 11)?

Tags: windows, services, openssh, ssh-tunnel

The accepted answer at the similar question [Automatic SSH tunneling from Windows - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/235395/automatic-ssh-tunneling-from-windows) recommends [Bitvise Tunnelier](http://www.bitvise.com/tunnelier) which requires a Windows client and **Windows server**.

My solution requires a **Linux OpenSSH server** and Windows clients. That other question focuses on tools a single user can set up and manage themselves. Even some of the answers there admit that those solutions can be inconvenient and unreliable.

In contrast, I'm looking for something that will run under the admin account without any action by the user and be rock solid. (Also, btw, that similar question has several answers that reference products which no longer exist and none of the answers there answer my question.)

On six (or more) business laptops for a small startup, we need to set up SSH tunnels that start at bootup and stay up all the time without any user intervention.

Each tunnel needs to have a local port, to establish a connection with a **Linux server** using ed25519 keys, to be monitored by autossh or similar so the tunnel stays connected. These need to be under the management of the admin account, not the user account.

I read that there is a built-in Windows 10 SSH client that became part of Windows starting from Windows 10 v1809 and Windows Server 2019. I also know that there is a Windows subsystem for Linux. I also just now briefly read about NSSM. However, I don't have any personal experience using Windows. I'm tasked with this because I know a little about using OpenSSH on Linux.

What tools would I need to use to set this up? The procedure ultimately has to be something that can be managed for a remote team. That means updates (such as changes to a server that require an update to client settings) need to be able to be pushed to remote clients in a fairly automated way.

What is a good approach to doing this on Windows 10 or 11? I would like to set up one proof of concept system.

Answer (score 1):

`autossh` alone should cover all the points you made. Autossh for Windows is available from this Github page:

https://github.com/jazzl0ver/autossh

Comment: It's good to know autossh exists for Windows. However, the solution needs a lot more than that. It needs something to configure and start multiple ssh tunnels, each of which can utilize autossh to keep it alive. That's why I was looking for something like systemd units (maybe NSSM?) as well as an idea how to package this up so updates can be pushed to remote clients.