# How to prevent SSH from disconnecting if it's been idle for a while

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I have a ssh connection to a machine which gets disconnected by that machine after 30 minutes of no user input. However, if I start something like `top`, the connection stays alive.
Since this is a client's machine, I can not reconfigure that machine's SSH server. So I am looking for a way to automatically detect idleness and start something like `top`. Kind of a "screensaver" for Bash.

I know that I can do that with `screen`, but unfortunately `screen` is not installed, and I can not install software. So I need to use what Bash offers.

To make it clear: I am looking for a solution that I start once after logging in, and then I want to use that terminal, walk away, come back two hours later and continue working, without typing anything before walking away. Also, I am not looking to tunnel stuff (for that I recommend the great tool [sshuttle](https://github.com/sshuttle))

Any ideas?

Comment: Just a quick note to make clear screen and Keepalive are not the same thing: for instance, if either ssh client or server gest disconnected, your ssh session will be terminated even if you have KeepAlive on, while a screen shell wouldn't be terminated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reliably keep an SSH tunnel open?](https://superuser.com/questions/37738/how-to-reliably-keep-an-ssh-tunnel-open)

Answer (score 174, accepted):

> To make it clear: I am looking for a solution that I start once after logging in, and then I want to use that terminal, walk away, come back two hours later and continue working, without typing anything before walking away.

The problem is that there is something (usually a firewall or load-balancer), which is dropping idle sessions.  If you configure session keepalives, the keepalives will prevent network devices from considering the session as idle.

**Linux / Unix / Cygwin OpenSSH fix**:
The simplest fix is to enable ssh client keepalives; this example will send an ssh keepalive every 60 seconds:

```
ssh -o "ServerAliveInterval 60" <SERVER_ADDRESS>
```

If you want to enable this on all your sessions, put this in your `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` or `~/.ssh/config`:

```
ServerAliveInterval 60
```

For more information, see the [`ssh_config` manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config)

**Putty Fix**:

Save this to your PuTTY "Default Settings"...

- Click on Connection
- Type 60 into "Seconds between keepalives"

[image: putty_screenshot]

Answer (score 66):

In addition to [Mike Pennington's answer](https://superuser.com/a/699680/352307), I would like to make you aware of `ServerAliveCountMax` too.

- The `ServerAliveInterval` will send a keepalive every x seconds (default is **0**, which disables this feature if not set to something else).
- This will be done `ServerAliveCountMax` times if no response is received. The default value of `ServerAliveCountMax` is **3** (see [manpage ssh_config](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config)).

Example: If you set `ServerAliveInterval` to **60** and leave `ServerAliveCountMax` as it is, this means the keepalive will only wait for `3 * 60 = 180 seconds =`  **3** minutes before quiting.

To increase this to e.g. 2 hours of trying to keep the connection alive, you can do:

**Per command:**

Therefore you should consider to set

```
ssh -o "ServerAliveInterval 60" -o "ServerAliveCountMax 120" <SERVER_ADDRESS>
```

**Persistent:**

To make it persistent write it to `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` (will apply system-wide) or `~/.ssh/config` (will apply user-only):

```
ServerAliveInterval 60
ServerAliveCountMax 120
```

#Note

As [dislick correctly pointed out](https://superuser.com/questions/699676/how-to-prevent-ssh-from-disconnecting-if-its-been-idle-for-a-while#comment2138274_1285742), this might not what you want, depending on your situation:

- If you would like to quickly terminate the session as soon as the server does not respond anymore, you should choose a low value for `ServerAliveCountMax`.
- If you are more interested in keeping an already established connection (e.g. you go by train and have a high latency), you should choose a higher value for `ServerAliveCountMax` to allow `ssh` to keep trying to reestablish the connection.

See also:

- [unix.stackexchange.com - What is the default idle timeout for OpenSSH?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150402/what-is-the-default-idle-timeout-for-openssh)

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is wrong. `ServerAliveCountMax` specifies the amount of server alive messages which may be sent *without* receiving any messages back from the server. If you want `ssh` to exit after it freezes (so that you can restart it) you should actually set `ServerAliveCountMax` to a *low* number. See the [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config) OP linked.

Comment: @dislick I had to think a little bit about this, but I think you are right depending on the context, hence I added a note to emphasize the context.

Comment: @dislick it seems to me that what is posted here is quite correct. Quoting the man page: "If, for example, `ServerAliveInterval` (see below) is set to 15 and `ServerAliveCountMax` is left at the default, if the server becomes unresponsive, `ssh` will disconnect after approximately 45 seconds."

Comment: Regarding the advice to set ServerAliveCountMax to 120, this completely borks the behavior most people want… the job of keepalives is first to detect network problems within a reasonable time… if the network fails, we want to abort the ssh session… However nobody wants to wait two hours to abort a dead network.  Set ServerAliveCountMax to 3 and ServerAliveInterval to 60… or something similar to detect failure as quickly as you want… I would point out that some keepalive loss is possible if the network is running at capacity… if this is you, adjust ServerAliveCountMax accordingly.

Answer (score 14):

I am using Mobaxterm and have also met with this problem. Mobaxterm also ships with an option to keep the client alive when the client is idle. Go to `Settings -> Configuration -> SSH`. There is section titled `SSH settings`, check the option `SSH keepalive`. Then it the problem should disappear.

[image]

Comment: does the "SSH keepalive" work in free edition... my session is getting disconnected even after checking up this option

Comment: Yes, it works. Your issue may have other causes.

Comment: I have the same problem as @samshers

Comment: Don't forget to restart MobaXterm after changing this setting.

Answer (score 3):

I usually do:

```
while true; do echo -n a; sleep 10; done
```

Answer (score 1):

It is never too late...

But if you only using non GUI than something better than `top` might be `crontab`.

Just create a bash script that `mkdir` and `rm` that folder each 5 minutes

or

send `/dev/null` to `/dev/null`. lol.

Comment: How can this prevent `ssh` from disconnecting?

Comment: @Noajm Have you tried if it works? Why `crontab`? You do not easily know from a script/program executed in `crontab` if a ssh session is active, and where (which tty) to send the output? There are also downsides to writing and deleting something on the disk (if you don't have a partition to write to?). BTW If it works with `top` maybe it works just running `date` every 5 minutes, but from a script ... please [edit] your post if you want to modify something.

Comment: Try it. I use it for my collage server and works good for me. It does kick me out after 2-3 days

Comment: @Noajm Hi. Some servers, for example university clusters with user and group quotas and many logins, disconnect you from an ssh session after a set amount of time, if you have not performed disk I/O operations, regardless of the connection parameters requested by your client. Others delete your data from common areas if they haven't had _recent_ access. In those cases you can think of I/O operations like `touch` to keep the session active. BTW If you have to keep an active session for 2 days I think you will find interesting [`screen`](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/).

Comment: A question: how did it work a script in crontab?? how did you find the session to keep alive? Can you say something more about it. Have a nice day.

Comment: @Hastur I mean I really do not know I know basic and still learning but I know I use this server just as cloud for me so I usually just through things to into it and then I scp things when I ever want. So, long time ago they kept kicking me out every 30 minutes when I do nothing. Then I just add this "run.sh" -> "cat /dev/null > /var/mail/UserID" to run every 5 minutes using Crontab ... and then things so far good

Comment: Thx for the answer. You are probably triggering some reaction with the internal email notification system. There are downsides. The first is that you go and rewrite the redirect file (`/var/mail/UserID`) every time. Specifically, you delete it (recreate it empty). And then there is the system burden for the triggered action. Finally, the additional work of the cron daemon. Try the canonical manner of the accepted answer removing your script from cron... `:-)`, it should work in other cases too...

Comment: @Hastur, you are right about the notification.. I keep getting this prompt saying "" You have new mail!" 

Comment: ...each 5 minutes I suppose ... BTW read about [`screen`](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/). You will find it really useful. Read about the possibility to **detach a session** and reconnect it (reattach) later. Give it a look on internet, maybe starting from something similar to **[>>this page<<](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-linux-screen/)** and this [other one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124897/how-do-i-detach-a-screen-session-from-a-terminal).

Comment: @Hastur  I really liked that so i can start a screen and run top on it and go back to my regular screen.... but i am having difficultly with their "commands for managing" so without GUI I will be screwed :)

Comment: ""I am having Mac not sure if that why I can't apply the commands"""

Comment: I tried it on the server ... haha I don't know I think I am causing a lot of disturbance when I run the "w" command...... so many pts/# taken by me

Answer (score 0):

How about a `watch 'mkdir temp; ls -l temp; rmdir temp`?