# Windows Terminal usually freezes ssh session after unlocking Windows

Tags: windows-10, terminal, freeze

Here's what happens:

I'm in an ssh session in Windows Terminal (Version: 1.11.3471.0, Windows 10 20H2).

I need to step away from my machine, so I lock it by typing Windows-L.

When I come back, usually after an hour or so, and unlock the machine, the tab with the ssh session in it is completely non-responsive. By that I mean that it doesn't respond to keyboard input at all. It's not that I've been logged out of the remote, just dead. No errors or anything in the terminal.

I know that the machine wasn't asleep because the monitor was displaying a pretty picture when I logged in to find the situation I described above. However, it's possible that it tried to go to sleep while I was away.

This happens fairly often, maybe every time I lock the machine for a while.

Any ideas as to why that's happening and how I might prevent it?

Thanks!

Comment: The same thing happens to me. I don't mind restarting the ssh session, but the terminal is completely unresponsive. I'm on Version: 1.15.2874.0.

Answer (score 1):

[SSH Escape Sequences (aka Kill Dead SSH Sessions)](https://lonesysadmin.net/2011/11/08/ssh-escape-sequences-aka-kill-dead-ssh-sessions/)

Enter, `~.` in the unresponsive terminal to terminate connection

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1174765)

Answer (score 0):

It is because the sessions are closed when no data is transmitted (something like your firewall or load-balancer is dropping idle sessions)

Check these two links for a solution:

- [linux - How to prevent SSH from disconnecting if it's been idle for a while - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/699676/how-to-prevent-ssh-from-disconnecting-if-its-been-idle-for-a-while)
- [timeout - Keep SSH session alive while computer sleep? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665267/keep-ssh-session-alive-while-computer-sleep)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, it's not a closed pipe. When that happens, the shell leaves a message saying that the pipe was closed, and I'm still able to use the open session.

In the case I'm asking about, the session freezes, and I have no option other than to close the tab.