# Setup ssh tunnel to access FTP on a remote server

Tags: ssh, tunnel, ssh-tunnel

I have an FTP server which is only accessible from 1 cloud machine (limited by IP).

Is it possible to create an SSH tunnel between my home computer and the cloud machine so I can access the FTP server directly from my home computer without having to ssh into the cloud machine first?

I have tried looking at the documentation for ssh tunnels and port forwarding but cant get my head round it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you haven't mentioned your home computer OS. I assume it is Window-based.
If so, here is my experience sharing, I have got the same scenario before.
i.e. from home computer to remote SSH server

According to your description, you want to do it automatically without SSH manually each time, right?

So here is the way go:

All you need is auto SSH tools,

**Window**
If you are window-based user can use [MyEnTunnel](http://nemesis2.qx.net/pages/MyEnTunnel)
There are example inside that I think it is enough. My case was Window-based.

**Linux**
and for linux, you may consider [autossh](http://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/), you may also refer to other post in similar question [How to reliably keep an SSH tunnel open?](https://superuser.com/questions/37738/how-to-reliably-keep-an-ssh-tunnel-open)

Comment: This is more along the lines of what I was looking for but appreciate the insight http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/ssh/ch11_02.htm