# Can I use SSH to serve a tunneled resource (HTML page) on a local network?

Tags: networking, ssh, http, localhost, ssh-tunnel

I have a remote-hosted resource (webapp) that I have to tunnel into a server to access remotely. I can complete the local port forwarding command using `-L` and then access the remote resource at `localhost:port` in my browser.

For simplicity and persistence, I'd like to tunnel into the remote host (using SSH with my key), but serve the web page locally, so that I can access it using different computers on my local network.

For instance:

```
Old way:
Remote-server  --|SSH_Tunnel|--  Local-host:port

New way:
Remote-server  --|SSH_Tunnel|--  Local-host:port || local-net:port == local_http-traffic == different-local-computer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr? Use `ssh -g …`.

---

I assume the command you're using is like

```
ssh -L 1234:server:5678 ssh_server
```

This will listen on `127.0.0.1:1234` (IPv4) and `[::1]:1234` (IPv6) on the local side. Local connections to any of these addresses will reach `server:5678` from the `ssh_server`. Other computers on your LAN cannot reach the tunnel because `127.0.0.1` and `[::1]` are loopback addresses; for any machine they mean the machine itself.

To make your tunnel available to other computers, bind it to an address they can reach. Let's say `192.168.0.14` is a valid address of the client that runs `ssh`; bind to it:

```
ssh -L 192.168.0.14:1234:server:5678 ssh_server
```

or to all available addresses (pick one command):

```
ssh -L 0.0.0.0:1234:server:5678 ssh_server                            # IPv4
ssh -L [::]:1234:server:5678 ssh_server                               # IPv6
ssh -L 0.0.0.0:1234:server:5678 -L [::]:1234:server:5678 ssh_server   # IPv4 and IPv6
```

The latter most "open" tunnel can also be created with `-g`. From [`man 1 ssh`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh):

> `-g` Allows remote hosts to connect to local forwarded ports.

`-g` is equivalent to `-o GatewayPorts=yes` and to `GatewayPorts yes` setting in `ssh_config` file. This excerpt from [`man 5 ssh_config`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config) explains it even better:

> `GatewayPorts`
>   Specifies whether remote hosts are allowed to connect to local forwarded ports. By default, `ssh(1)` binds local port forwardings to the loopback address. This prevents other remote hosts from connecting to forwarded ports. GatewayPorts can be used to specify that `ssh` should bind local port forwardings to the wildcard address, thus allowing remote hosts to connect to forwarded ports. The argument must be `yes` or `no`. The default is `no`.

So:

```
ssh -g -L 1234:server:5678 ssh_server
```

Notes:

- Don't forget to open the chosen port in your firewall.
- You may find [`autossh`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/autossh) useful…
- … along with `ExitOnForwardFailure` option of `ssh` (explained in [`man 5 ssh_config`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config)).
- In general a HTTP server may reject URLs it doesn't consider as its own. You said `localhost:port` works in your browser. In case URLs like `http://192.168.0.14:1234` don't work despite the tunnel, check the server setup.

Additional resources:

- [How to reliably keep an SSH tunnel open?](https://superuser.com/q/37738/432690)

Comment: Excellent answer - unfortunately it did not solve my problem, as it appears I have restrictions I didn't consider in asking this question. I'm marking your answer as the accepted one and will ask a new question with my different constraints.