# How to connect to local KVM guest via remote SSH tunnel to ssh

Tags: networking, ssh, tunnel, linux-kvm, libvirt

I try to set up a connection as follows:

```
ssh -f -N -L 5916:localhost:22 developer@192.168.100.210
developer@192.168.100.210's password:
```

It asks for a password , but the connection doesn't work.

```
nmap my.remote.ip -p 5916

Host is up (0.0038s latency).

PORT     STATE  SERVICE
5916/tcp closed unknown
```

In virtual machine `ssh` is working:

```
ssh  developer@192.168.100.210
developer@192.168.100.210's password: 
Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-69-generic x86_64)
```

I have disabled firewall on host for test.

The tunnel work more or less, but only for localhost:

```
 ssh developer@localhost -p 5916
developer@localhost's password: 
Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-69-generic x86_64)
```

This is the response from the virtual machine.

What am I missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use SSH to serve a tunneled resource (HTML page) on a local network?](https://superuser.com/questions/1326962/can-i-use-ssh-to-serve-a-tunneled-resource-html-page-on-a-local-network)

Comment: Note: the title says "remote SSH tunnel", which kinda suggests remote port forwarding; still you used `-L` which is local port forwarding.

Comment: this version works : ssh -g -f -N -L 5915:localhost:22 developer@192.168.100.210